# Array move left (C)

Tags: c

I have small problem with array in C.
I have 4 elements array. I must make something like this:

initial array

```
0 0 0 0
```

input 1

```
0 0 0 1
```

input 2

```
0 0 1 2
```

input 3

```
0 1 2 3
```

input 4

```
1 2 3 4
```

input 5

```
2 3 4 5
```

input 6

```
3 4 5 6
```

I haven't any idea; can you please give me some tips?

Comment: What are you asking? are you searching for someone to do it for you? Have you tried something? post the code.

Comment: I programming arduinio and i make code opening door but this is not what I want. im my program when i push # array is reset and next 4 number is password and when i push # code is accepted. I need something without #(reset), when i push some random numbers and last 4 numbers is my password i push # and open door. 
Code : http://ideone.com/DhYPIi

Answer (score 2):

you can shift data in your array like this

lets say you have a global array variable named 'a'
you can call 'add' function to add data to end of the array

```
int a[4];

void add(int element)
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        a[i] = a[i+1];

    a[3] = element;
}
```

Comment: Would there be merit in `enum { A_SIZE = 4 }; int a[A_SIZE];` and `for (int i = 0; i < A_SIZE - 1; i++)` and `a[A_SIZE-1] = element;`? There's also a solution that uses `memmove()` — but not `memcpy()`! — but on the whole I prefer what you wrote.

Comment: thanks for idea ! 
I make this, little modifiy your but it works !

 dostep[4]=key;
 for (int i=0; i <4; i++)
      {
        
        dostep[i]=dostep[i+1];
    
      } 
i use one more auxilary element :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I did a similar project. Rather than shifting every element every time you press a new key, it just checks against the "correct" entry (`code[]`) starting at the current position when you press #.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ALEN 4

// for testing, just use stdout/stdin...
void accept() { printf("\nACCEPT\n"); }
void deny() { printf("\nDENY\n"); }
char input() { return (char)getchar(); }


int main() {
    char a[ALEN];
    char code[ALEN] = {'1','2','3','4'};
    int pos = 0;
    char keypressed;
    while (keypressed = (char)getchar()) {
        if (keypressed == '#') {
            if (a[pos] == code[0] && a[(pos+1)%4] == code[1] && a[(pos+2)%4] == code[2] && a[(pos+3)%4] == code[3]) {
                accept();
            } else {
                deny();
            }
        } else {
            a[pos] = keypressed;
            pos++;
            if (pos == ALEN) {
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//code your initialisation and your key_hook
//then call tab = shift_and_add(oldtab, new); with new, your new integer

int *shift_and_add(int *oldtab, int new, unisgned int size)
{    
    unsigned int i = 1;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    newtab = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    while (i < size)
    {
        newtab[j] = oldtab[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    newtab[j] = new;
    return (newtab);
}
```